Editing the question to add the accepted answer
Someone asks a question.
Someone else posts an answer.
The OP up-votes and accepts the answer.
Then the OP edits their question, adds an "Edit: Solution" section, and copies (the gist of) the accepted answer into the question.
I edit the question, and I remove the entire "Edit: Solution" section, effectively undoing the OP's last edit.
The OP adds a comment saying that they are unhappy about my edit.
Please advise.

I found these, which look similar but do not seem to be about the exact same situation:
Can/Should I edit my question to an add answer?
Answer a question... inside the question

Raise a moderator flag on the question. (Normally, what you did—editing it out—is the correct course of action. But, when you get pushback, as you described here, you should raise a custom moderator flag and let one of us step in. Note that this is generally what you should do whenever you try to enforce the site rules in good faith but get pushback.)

And drink a cup of tea. With a biscuit, let yourself go. What else can you do when you meet yet another human being using the site as they please rather than as intended?
